# Button style appears different in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Prod Expected: [image]

Result : [image]

Prod and Local had different antd design icons version so i thought it would be it but after installing the version on prod to my local machine it did not help. Any help appreciated

```
    import styled from "styled-components";
import {Button} from "antd";
import {Translation} from "react-i18next";

const SendViaEmail = styled(Button)`
  height: 36px !important;
  background-color: ${props => props.disabled ? "#D7D8D8" : "#1B2F55"} !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 12px; !important;
  font-weight: bold; !important;
  display: flex !important;
  line-height: 16px !important;
  justify-content: space-around !important;
`;


export default class SendViaEmailButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <Translation>
            {(t) => {
                return <SendViaEmail onClick={() => this.props.onClick()} disabled={this.props.disabled}>
                    <div style={{marginRight: "10px"}}><img src={send} alt={'Send'}/></div>
                    <div>{t('sendViaEmail')}</div>
                </SendViaEmail>

            }}
        </Translation>
    }
}
```

prod
[image]

local
[image]

Comment: Can you check which css files are being imported on your production build? maybe inspect them on the browser to find which styles are being applied and from where

Comment: @IvanS95 that is correct prod styles looks different that localhost , why that could be happening? thanks

Comment: Again, try checking which css files are being included in your page, maybe share an screenshot of the `head` tag of your production site, maybe it is including a different stylesheet

Comment: @IvanS95 edited

Comment: The information is not particularly helpful, yes, the most likely issue is that different styles are being applied, but you need to actually find where those styles are, look for the stylesheet that is overriding the styles, you should find the file on the top right corner of each CSS rule in the inspector, see where you have declared those styles, if you have the same class on two different places on your CSS, the last one declared will override the styles of the first

Comment: @IvanS95 thank you for your time i have added two style screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217004/discussion-between-artjom-prozorov-and-ivans95).